# How does gevent interact with threading.local data?

Tags: gevent

Will data stored in a threading.local be unique to a specific co-routine, or will it continue to be unique to a python thread?

Answer (score 12):

According to the documentation of gevent.monkey at http://www.gevent.org/gevent.monkey.html, the thread and threading modules become greenlet-based. "Thread-local storage becomes greenlet-local storage."

Comment: - if you've monkey patched it.

Comment: @Ivo :) I figured that went without saying.